# how to create a city map

Tags: cesium, create

I would like to create a map of a small zone in Cesium. It would be a 3d map, with some building appearing with real size like this => https://cesiumjs.org/NewYork/

I have searched about how to do this kind of building representation using KML, CityKML, GLTF, or COLLADA.

Now, my problem is I don't understand how to I create this data. I searched for UI tools in order to

=> import a building model (gltf for exemple)
=> placing it at a location on the map 
=> adding some information to the building like building name
=> export that model (as gltf/json, or kml, or any) so I can import in Cesium.

Is there tools to do this ? I can't find any

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to sign up for a [Cesium ion account](https://cesium.com/ion/) to use e.g. the online converters or the [Blender plug-in](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium-ion-blender-addon).

Next steps could be…

- reading more on the 3D Tiles Ecosystem:
  https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/3d-tiles
- browsing the GitHub repository of Analytical Graphics, Inc. for some additional (converter) tools:
  https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc

Comment: thank you for your reply. 

The thinkgs I do not exactly understand is the following. To have a tileset that display a metadata for everybuilding like the new york map

1) When I create a tileset, do I have to upload all the building one by one ? or upload a big block of data? 

2) how do I "bind" the metadata to the buildings? I tried uploading a GLTF to cesium ION, but I don't understand a way to give to each building informations>

Comment: for exemple => https://bit.ly/2JEvngg in this exemple, I uploaded a single GLTF with a set of buildings,  when I click on the buildings, they all return me the b3dm but not individual information of each model I clicked.